# How to get review form page url in view.phtml in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, list.phtml

How to get review form page url in **view.phtm**l in magento
I want to get the **Be first to review this product url in view.phtml file**

Answer (score 2):

you can get url

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array(
           'id'        => $productid,
           'category'  => $categoryid
        ));?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a>
```

Comment: How to pass category id.. Is that mandatory..?

Comment: go to `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php` and check `getReviewsUrl` method. i also think product id will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get that url

If you already Added review form in your view page via layout then add this code in your `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo Mage::getUrl('review/product/list/id', array('id' => $_product->getId()));
```

Comment: It is better to accept the solution rather posting your own identical answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

In catalog.xml file, add a new child block as below -

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="view.review" as="review" template="review/url.phtml"/>
```

now create a new phtml file at "review/url.phtml" and add below content -

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php
    $url = Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array(
            'id'        => $_product->getId(),
            'category'  => $_product->getCategoryId()
            ));
?>
<p class="no-rating"><a href="#review-form">
         <?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?>
     </a>
</p>
```

now in view.phtml file add your link where you want using -

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review') ?>
```

hope this should work for you